# How to extract .bundle file on mac os x?

Tags: macos, mac

My problem is that I want to install VMware workstation on mac os x 10.8
I downloaded it from the internet and its extension was .bundle. I searched how to extract it on the internet, and I found this command

```
sudo sh [file name]
```

I do this, but I face this message:

> stat: illegal option -- -
>
> usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file …]

What does this mean and how I can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Bundles are just directories.  Open up that Terminal again and "cd" into the bundle to see the contents.  This won't install the app, though.

You neglected to show the full [file name], but it's quite likely that the filename needs to be surrounded in double-quotes.  But, VMWare Workstation is NOT supported for the Mac, so I'm not sure this will work as you intend...

Comment: when i installed vmware i installed the version for linux , is not the same ? 
i tried to execute command cd for the bundle but it says it's not a directory 
the full name as i installed is "VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle"

Comment: No, it's not the same.  Although OS X has Unix underpinnings, it does not have the same binary/assembly format as other Unix/Linux OSes.